Is there a global information system that publishes about medicine recalls worldwide?
The Dutch investigative journalists/documentary makers Zembla published a few years ago about impurities in medicine:

'Paracetamol contaminated with a carcinogen,' is the news published by Zembla and NRC this summer. The journalists had paracetamol from the world's largest raw material producer, Chinese Anqiu Lu'an Pharmaceutical, tested. The analysis showed that it contained a carcinogenic substance. Where in the world this contaminated paracetamol ended up is not known.

One of the impurities they spoke about was N-nitrosodimethylamine (NDMA). The full documentary is available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3o0Syaptqg, audio is partial English and Dutch but auto-translated subtitles in English can be enabled too.
I was surprised to find out that independent countries did recall medicine while others didn't. It seems that even if there is a suspicion of impurities that the inspection at bests informs drug stores but not always the doctors or patients who prescribe or take it. I'm wondering if there is a global system (or app) available for doctors or consumers that can inform about recalls of specific medicine by generic or brand name, anywhere in the world. I'm aware of similar push notification, information systems for specific food products that are recalled in The Netherlands, such as the app for pregnant woman 'ZwangerHap' by the Dutch nutrition center (voedingscentrum).
